# Writing Null values Into a Plist file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I tried writing some data into a plist file...i could'nt because it had some null value's.. is there a way by which we can write null values into a plist??

Can anyone suggest an approach for this ??

Comment: Why you need that ? Null is returned by default for any non-existing keys in NSDictionary.

Comment: Could you give a example?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski the problem is with writing to the plist file :) My data has both null and non null values.. can't filter the null values and then write :(

Comment: @Larme: bool value=[dictionaryName writeToFile:path atomically:yes]; returns NO if the dictionary has Null Values :(

Comment: please specify _your_ _null_ value, because if the value is `nil`, they key does not exist, so I assume your _null_ value is a kind of object which you refere _null_ in spite of that is not `nil`.

Comment: can you supply some code samples? i cannot see why you can't check for null before you write the values to the plist

Comment: Im writing the data into the plist before sending the data to the server.. it contains lots of values and for some keys if user won't select anything from UI the value should be null... so i don't want to change the value and want to write it inside the plist as it is...

Answer (score 0):

I think the priority of writing these types of files is for garbage collection, such as doing a search with multiple errors and that list of errors is really just garbage anyway-so that would be for collecting the errors which are deleted in the null file... Don't know if this helps but it is primarily the method of creating a null file as I have seen used. Obviously I don't want to insult your intelligence but null is just that nothing in the file and therefore it is automatically deleted afterward.
It also appears your bool is working as expected. If or a for might be more effective if you want to write the contents and send the exceptions or errors to null as I mentioned above.